# Jackson: Deserialize JSON array from JSON object into Java List

Tags: java, spring, jackson

I have been stumbled by this for a while. I have a Spring application and would like to parse the following JSON:

```
{
  "metadata": {...}
  "response": {
    "objects": [
      {
        "name": "someName",
        "properties": [<array_of_properties>]
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

into a list of the following Java objects:

```java
public class MyClass {
  String name;
  List<CustomProperties> customProperties;
}
```

Meaning, I want to extract only the `objects` array and parse only that. I have tried using a custom deserializer and that works, but I had to do:

```java
@JsonDeserialize(using=MyDeserializer.class)
public class MyClassList extends ArrayList<MyClass>{}
```

and then:

```java
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<MyClass> list = objectMapper.readValue(json, MyClassList.class)
```

Is there anyway to avoid extending `ArrayList`, since currently I am doing that in order to be able to access the `.class` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can define your json structure with a couple of classes

```
public class MyJson {
  private MyResponse response;
  ...
}

public class MyResponse {
  private List<MyClass> objects;
  ...
}

public class MyClass {
  String name;
  List<CustomProperty> customProperties;
  ...
}
```

than you can use Jackson to parse the json string to `MyJson` class, no special `@JsonDeserialize` is needed

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyJson myJson = objectMapper.readValue(json, MyJson.class);
List<MyClass> list =  myJson.getResponse().getObjects();
```

Keep in mind, this code is only a draft, all classes should have setters (and getters) and some null checks are required

Comment: Thank you, shahaf!

However, I was hoping to avoid the need for wrapper classes. I am not against it, and if it's the only way I will go with it, but is there no direct way to tell Jackson: Hey, I have this JSON string and this deserializer which returns a `List` of objects. Use it!

Comment: @NikolaToshev, sry I don't familiar with one, because JAVA is statically type, a parsing of dynamic strings like JSON, is more construct, and one need to define the type and structure, the other option is to use `JsonObject` or `JsonNode` and traverse the tree to the specific key, more error prone...

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this. I feel this would be cleaner

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class Wrapper{
  private Response response;
  //setters, getters
}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class Response{
  private List<MyClass> objects;
  //setters, getters
}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class MyClass {
  String name;
  List<CustomProperties> customProperties;
  //setters, getters
}

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Wrapper wrapper = objectMapper.readValue(json, Wrapper.class)
```

You can extrat objects and consequently CustomProperties by traversing the list. You can declare only fields which you are interested in and ignore others by `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)`(for example i have not included metadata)